# ViewPager's children's onDraw method are not always called?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using a ViewPager to display a list a of custom views. My custom views extend View and override the onDraw() method. In addition to my drawing code, my onDraw() method also contains a log statement so I can debug if the onDraw() method is being called. It is only called occasionally. For example, if I swipe back and forth between two pages, the onDraw() method is usually not called. Is ViewPager doing some sort of caching? Is there a way to ensure that my custom view's onDraw() method is called everytime the custom view because visible?

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager has property called offscreen page limit which defines how many pages to the left and right of the current page should be retained (i.e. not destroyed while swiping). You may change its value using ViewPager's `setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)` method. By default it's set to 1 so at the beginning there should be 2 pages created (first one and the one on its right) and hence you should notice two invocations of onDraw method. I'm afraid that it's not possible to acheive the behaviour you want (onDraw method being called on each swipe) by changing mentioned limit because ViewPager does not allow to set offset page limit to 0 (setting does not result in error, but in that case default value is used).